# API for two player android app

Tags: php, android, performance, api, android-studio

I want to make android app in which two players will be there both have 10 cards (not poker cards), Now my concern is,
when player one select any cards, that card needs to be displayed at player 2's device something like real time.
So i want to know what is the best way to do it. at API side? I am not making a game to Play service will not be part of it.

And i want to use Json response with PHP for API!

Comment: As far as I can tell,  this is going to be a real-time application and needs to use sockets for such interactions. Please someone proove me am wrong.

Comment: Okay, Any example or suggestion how to do it, OR where can i find the same example?

Comment: Check out this chat tutorial on updating all viewers whenever an event occurs: https://medium.com/@martin.sikora/node-js-websocket-simple-chat-tutorial-2def3a841b61